# Ansible csvfile lookup, multiple rows?

Tags: csv, ansible

I have a csvlookup where it lookups the value "Main" in column 0. And returns the value in column 1 per below.

The problem is that this only returns the first result, I want to return all results that match "Main".

How can this be achieved?

```
msg: "{{ lookup('csvfile', 'Main file=vlans.csv delimiter=, col=1') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

No way to achieve this with default csvfile lookup plugin.

First option – use linux tools with `lines` lookup:

```
{{ lookup('lines', 'grep ^Main vlans.csv | cut -d, -f2', wantlist=true) }}
```

Second option – copy [standard](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/cdec853e37d2342346f54e51f4ec4bfbd2ee0031/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/csvfile.py) `csvfile.py` into `./lookup_plugins` and modify `read_csv` function a bit:

```
        r = []
        for row in creader:
            if row[0] == key:
                r.append(row[int(col)])
        if len(r) > 0:
            return r
```